# Eloquent select using the wrong class?

Tags: php, laravel, inheritance, eloquent

Context: Trying to extend Laravel models from a database table. Table `models` linked to `App\Models\BootableModel`, `App\Models\User` extends this class.

I have the following code:

```
<?php
    class BootableModel extends Model
    {
        protected $table = 'models';

        protected $fillable = [
            'name',
            'class',
            'table',
        ];

        public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
        {
            $this->bootFromDatabase();
            parent::__construct($attributes);
        }

        private function bootFromDatabase()
        {
            $class = static::class;
            $bModClass = self::class;
            Log::debug($class);
            Log::debug($bModClass);
            //$bootableModel = DB::table('models')->where('class', $class)->first();
            $bootableModel = $bModClass::where('class', $class)->first();
            if(!$bootableModel) {
                return;
            }
            Log::debug($bootableModel->id);
```

The debug of `$bModClass` shows `App\Models\BootableModel` as expected (`self` vs `static`), but for some reason the `$bModClass::where` is trying to query the `users` table. Using a direct reference to `App\Models\BootableModel::class` does not change this, so it's not `self::class` that is the issue. The debug output as proof:

```
[2021-02-21 17:33:39] local.DEBUG: App\Models\User
[2021-02-21 17:33:39] local.DEBUG: App\Models\BootableModel
```

It should never try to access `User::where()`, and as such, it should never try to use `User::$table` either, but somehow it does.

Is Laravel doing some weird reflection, or is this normal PHP behavior? Is there a way around this?

**Update:**

I have found a workaround, but I'm not satisfied with this being the correct/only solution:

```
        public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
        {
            parent::__construct($attributes);
            static::bootFromDatabase();
        }

        public static function bootFromDatabase()
        {
            $class = static::class;
            $bModClass = self::class;
            if($class === $bModClass) {
                return;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried `self::where(...)` instead of `$bModClass::where(...)` ?

Similar situation:

```
class Base {
    public static function where()
    {
        return 'where from base';
    }
    
    public static function getName()
    {
        return self::where();
    }
}

class User extends Base {
    public static function where()
    {
        return 'where from user';
    }
}

echo User::getName();
```

Output: `where from base`

Comment: I've tried self::where, App\Models\BootableModel::where, and static::where, as well as a stored reference to each, but until I made the function static they all returned the wrong table. Making the function static seems to have resolved the issue, but doesn't really explain the behavior and feels like a workaround rather than a solution

Comment: Actually PHP has some weird behaviors when it comes to OOP principles and architecture and it's totally because of PHP's own implementation. For example, when you use non-static members, it's scope will be object-specific and so, it will not obey common OOP concepts those are normal in languages such as Java or C#. BTW I'm happy that the solution worked for you.